# Android parse KML file for time

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to work out how to obtain the travel time between two locations (walking, driving etc...).

As I understand it, the only way to do this accurately is by retrieving a KML file from google, then parsing it.

Research has shown that it then needs to be parsed with SAX. The problem is, I can't seem to work out how to extract the correct variables (the time). Does anybody know if / how this can be done?

Many thanks for your help,

Pete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing XML (what KML basically is), using a SAX-Parser: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/blog/324/entry-2683-parsing-xml-in-java-part-1-sax/

```
<kml>
  <Document>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Route</name>
      <description>Distance: 1.4&#160;mi (about 30 mins)<br/>Map data &#169;2011 Tele Atlas </description>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

In the example you can see, that the guessed time is stored in the "description"-Tag. It's saved in the last "Placemark"-Tag in the KML-File and it has a "`<name>Route</name>`"-Tag.

Getting this Tag with the SAX-Parser and extracting the time using regex should be easy done.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand this though, it's how to then get the time field from this.

Comment: Can you post an example KML file that you're receiving from Google?

Comment: Sure, here's an example:  http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&source=s_d&saddr=bn24bs&daddr=50.8473,-0.105407&geocode=FRDDBwMdRi3-_yn1AbQJjIV1SDGgj2YSrwy4YA%3BFUTeBwMdQWT-_w&hl=en&mra=ltm&dirflg=w&sll=50.84643,-0.111985&sspn=0.014578,0.042272&ie=UTF8&ll=50.844999,-0.112181&spn=0.013874,0.0421&z=15&output=kml

Comment: Okay, as i looked into it, i found that the guessed time for the route isn't saved in an extra field. It's saved in the "description"-Field of the Route. I updated the Post, have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my JSOUP implementation for getting tracks

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<LatLng>> getAllTracks() {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<LatLng>> allTracks = new ArrayList<ArrayList<LatLng>>();

    try {
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        InputStream json = MyApplication.getInstance().getAssets().open("track.kml");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(json));
        String str;

        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            buf.append(str);
        }

        in.close();
        String html = buf.toString();
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());
        ArrayList<String> tracksString = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Element e : doc.select("coordinates")) {
            tracksString.add(e.toString().replace("<coordinates>", "").replace("</coordinates>", ""));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < tracksString.size(); i++) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> oneTrack = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            ArrayList<String> oneTrackString = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(tracksString.get(i).split("\\s+")));
            for (int k = 1; k < oneTrackString.size(); k++) {
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(oneTrackString.get(k).split(",")[0]), Double.parseDouble(oneTrackString.get(k)
                        .split(",")[1]));
                oneTrack.add(latLng);
            }
            allTracks.add(oneTrack);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return allTracks;
}
```